# Pandas: groupby some data

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
datetime    city    state   country shape   duration (seconds)  duration (hours/min)    comments    date posted latitude    longitude
10/10/1949 20:30    san marcos  tx  us  cylinder    2700    45 minutes  This event took place in early fall around 1949-50. It occurred after a Boy Scout meeting in the Baptist Church. The Baptist Church sit 4/27/2004   29.8830556  -97.9411111
10/10/1949 21:00    lackland afb    tx      light   7200    1-2 hrs 1949 Lackland AFB&#44 TX. Lights racing across the sky &amp; making 90 degree turns on a dime.  12/16/2005  29.38421    -98.581082
10/10/1955 17:00    chester (uk/england)        gb  circle  20  20 seconds  Green/Orange circular disc over Chester&#44 England 1/21/2008   53.2    -2.916667
10/10/1956 21:00    edna    tx  us  circle  20  1/2 hour    My older brother and twin sister were leaving the only Edna theater at about 9 PM&#44...we had our bikes and I took a different route home  1/17/2004   28.9783333  -96.6458333
10/10/1960 20:00    kaneohe hi  us  light   900 15 minutes  AS a Marine 1st Lt. flying an FJ4B fighter/attack aircraft on a solo night exercise&#44 I was at 50&#44000&#39 in a &quot;clean&quot; aircraft (no ordinan  1/22/2004   21.4180556  -157.8036111
```

I try do group by `state`
I use

```
result = df.groupby("state").\
    agg({"state": pd.Series.nunique, "duration (seconds)": np.sum}).\
    rename(columns={"state": "frequency", "duration (seconds)": "whole time"}).\
    reset_index()
```

But it returns error `TypeError: must be str, not float`.
I try to convert `duration (seconds)` but it returns
`duration (seconds)`.
How can I check this problem?

Comment: what's actually throwing the error? does
`result = df.groupby("state").agg({"state": pd.Series.nunique})` work? (ie, half of your groupby)

Comment: we have no idea where the error is coming from. poast the whole error bro

Answer (score 0):

do something like:

```
# Group df by df.state, then apply a sum lambda function to df.duration(seconds)
df.groupby('state')['duration (seconds)'].apply(lambda x:x.mean())
```

Or if you want a rolling sum:

```
df.groupby('state')['duration (seconds)'].apply(lambda x:x.rolling(center=False,window=2).sum())
```